# MMQGIS Geocoding Error

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, csv, mmqgis

I have a file with over 27,000 addresses, and I'm trying to geocode it using the OpenStreetMap/Nominatim web service via the MMQGIS plugin on QGIS 2.10.

I keep getting an error after about 30 minutes of this plugin running in which 0 addresses get geocoded. Presumably, it is because my .csv file is not clean.

*An error has occured while executing Python code:*

*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/derekkaden/.qgis2/python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 1198, in run
    shapefilename, notfoundfile, fields, service, 1)
  File "/Users/derekkaden/.qgis2/python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_library.py", line 1901, in mmqgis_geocode_web_service
    attributes.append(unicode(row[z], 'utf-8').strip())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 14: invalid continuation byte*

Is anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: you might be trying to geocode too many records at once... try geocoding a subset of 100 or so and see if that works...

Comment: Perhaps you could give details about the error you're getting. This would help people familiar with the plugin know what is going wrong.

Comment: I just added the error message. Also, I've tested about 35 addresses and those geocoded fine. There shouldn't be a limit to how many addresses one can geocode in mmqgis//osm (Google is 2,500). Correct?

Comment: @DerekKaden I think I have seen this - how are you setting the name of the output shapefile and 'not found' file - by typing in the path, or by browsing to them? I have seen by typing in the paths, you get errors...

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question and you are asking three, of which the last is probably too broad in its own right.  I recommend using the [edit] button to focus this question on what appears to be its main point i.e. the error that you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks, @mapBaker. It is not the output shapefile. Since I had success with a small sample, I've concluded it has something to do with my large .csv file not being properly cleaned.

Comment: @DerekKaden in that case, try using LibreOffice Calc to open the CSV and see if there are any special characters in the file that MMQGIS might be blowing up on - this past week I had a problem with this tool crashing, and lo and behold when I opened up a MS Office-created CSV in LibreOffice, there were all these special characters gumming up the works! I removed them, and no issues in MMQGIS!

Comment: Great, I'll check out LibreOffice Calc. Haven't used that before. Thanks for the tips!